# How does opening a file descriptor effect memory

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, files, grep

Let’s say I have a 250MB file that I read from by opening a file descriptor. Does the entire file get dumped into memory and stay there until I close the file descriptor?
How does that differ from parsing data from the same file with a command like sed, grep, or awk?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The kernel will buffer the file in memory according to the kernel policy and memory demand situation. The whole file may end up in memory, and it will possibly stay in memory even after the file descriptor is closed until the buffers need to be reused, so if you run the same application with the same file again directly afterwards, it will be much faster. Or only parts may end up in memory, read after each other.

All applications behave the same in that respect, it doesn't matter what the application is. Though there are different ways of opening a file, and this may affect details of how everything works.